# How to set favicon of window opened from window.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

This is not working when the window is opened using the `window.open` method.

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="@Url.Content("~/Contents/favicon.ico")"/>
```

On top of window